# Using plt.show() how can I define the background color?

Tags: matplotlib

When I visualize a plot, the default background color is something like gray. I want to have a white end, like the one that I obtain when I save the plot.
[image: this is what I see with plt.show()]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like any other patch, the figure itself has a `set_facecolor()` method.

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_facecolor("w")
```

You may also directly use the `facecolor` argument of `plt.figure()`

```
fig = plt.figure(facecolor="w")
```

A third option is to set the respective rc Parameter. This can either be done in the top of the script

```
plt.rcParams["figure.facecolor"] = "w"
```

or by chaning the [matplotlib rc file](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

Note that from matplotlib version 2.0 on, the default facecolor for figures is actually white, so updating matplotlib is the fourth option available.